# Datatables get row Data without clicking on it

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables to show a list of messages.

I need a way to get a specific row of data based off an id being passed to the page on the Query string.

ex. www.webpage.com?id=2

I already have the id in a jQuery variable.
Now I just need to access the DataTable row associated with that id.

Basically, I need to reference the row, without having clicked on it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried the `fnSelect()` function from dataTables?

Comment: I haven't ... what does that one do? I did look over their API list but I don't see that one currently listed? Is it new or old perhaps?

Comment: Do you just need a reference to the <tr> element or do you mean the row's data in an array or something?

Comment: That depends Gigo ... on what DataTables needs, in order to reference the data in that row. 
Currently, I'm using var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr); to get the data when I'm actually clicking on the row. So I need a way to replace the nTr, which is just "this" when I click on the row.

Comment: @CraigThompson: apologies, fnSelect is a function in TableTools, which is a dataTables add-on. I use it so often, I don't differentiate.  Here's the reference: http://www.datatables.net/extras/tabletools/api

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe I'll have to look into that if I don't get one of these others to work. Thank you for the information :-)

Answer (score 8):

One way could be to use `fnGetPosition` and `fnGetData`

```
var rowIndex = table.fnGetPosition( $("some selector").closest('tr')[0] );
//some selector = should select some hidden element inside a row that 
//contains the relevant id
var aData = table.fnGetData( rowIndex  );
alert(aData[0]);// will show first column data
```

**Here a working** [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/CMR5Y/) **of an external button that selects row with specific ID**

**Another example that select the row with specific ID on page load(ready)**[jsfiddle example N#2](http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/CMR5Y/3/)

Take a look at the function

```
$("#wow").click(function() {

    var rowIndex = table.fnGetPosition($("#example input[value=\'TridentVal\']").closest('tr')[0]);
    alert(rowIndex);
    var aData = table.fnGetData(rowIndex);
    alert(aData[0]); // will show first column data
});​
```

This is the way to select an input with relevant data... :

```
$("#example input[value=\'TridentVal\']")
```

`example` is table id , replace *TridentVal* with the needed ID

Comment: This looks promising ... how would I go about referencing the specific row I need using fnGetPosition?
For Example ... the row where ID = 2?

Comment: Do I just need to say .closest('tr')[2] ?

Comment: nope, leave the `.closest('tr')[0]` as it is... do you have a column that holds the id of the row ? if not add some hidden `input` (`style="display:none"`) with `value="ID_OF_THE_ROW"`...

Comment: yes, the first column in the Datatable is a hidden column containing the messageID

Comment: I'm just not familiar with the way I would replace "some selector" with the appropriate row id.

Comment: @CraigThompson , I have updated my answer with working example... http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/CMR5Y/

Comment: As I said before, there is no button ... there is no click. There is only an ID that corresponds to a table row with the same id number in a hidden column named 'MessageID'

Comment: posted another solution - that do the same on page load http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/CMR5Y/3/ , You better explain yourself better next time in your question...

Answer (score 3):

First you have to get your table row using jQuery.

```
var $rowNode = $('#myTable').find('tbody tr:eq(0)').get(0);
```

Then you use `fnGetData` to get the row data.

```
var data = table.fnGetData($rowNode);
```

`fnGetData` acccepts a row node or an integer, so you can pass the row index as parameter too.

[**demo**](http://live.datatables.net/ituguf/edit#preview)

Comment: how would I go about getting the appropriate row index from the id that was passed in?

Comment: @CraigThompson In my code I'm using `eq` which gets the `tr` on the index 0, you can change it to `eq(1)` , `eq(2)`, `eq(n)`. Or use `index()`.

Comment: @CraigThompson Why do you want to get the row index, you can pass the row node as parameter.

Comment: So I can say .find('tbody tr:eq(' + msgID + ')').get(0);
for the specific row I'm looking for?

Comment: @CraigThompson If `msgID` data is on the equivalent row, yes.

Comment: msgID is the message ID that's being passed on the query string ... it's also the unique id in the hidden MessageID field of the Datatable.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the TableTools extension, then you can use fnSelect().  From the [docs](http://www.datatables.net/extras/tabletools/api):

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example1').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sRowSelect": "single"
        }
    } );

    // Select the first row in the table automatically
    var oTT = TableTools.fnGetInstance( 'example1' );
    oTT.fnSelect( $('#example tbody tr')[0] );
});
```

You'd of course want to modify the selector so it chooses the row that has your id.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to modify that selector to choose the correct row.

Answer (score 0):

fnGetData is now obsolete.
this documents the cell().data() access pattern in the current version
https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()